# crash log in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, logging

I need help to understand the crash log. The app works fine on my simulator but it crashes in device.

my simulator is run with:-**iPhone Simulator 225, iPhone OS 4.1 (iPhone 4/8B5091b)**

this is my device crash log:-

```
Incident Identifier: CD0E8B93-5CF9-402C-9787-4B175C51A690
CrashReporter Key:   1961913be3204fe8cb5a39c1e00ac0f03a452876
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         My Game[1115]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2968E5FB-96DD-443D-B386-D68F08E9345E/My Game.app/My Game
Identifier:      My Game
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-12-29 23:39:15.753 -0500
OS Version:      **iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)**
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35de3ad0 0x35d5a000 + 563920
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35de3abe 0x35d5a000 + 563902
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35de3ab2 0x35d5a000 + 563890
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35dfad5e 0x35d5a000 + 658782
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x374f2a00 0x3748d000 + 416256
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32d9d8d8 0x32d95000 + 35032
6   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x374f0100 0x3748d000 + 405760
7   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x374f0178 0x3748d000 + 405880
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x374f02a0 0x3748d000 + 406176
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32d9bf28 0x32d95000 + 28456
10  CoreFoundation                 0x3759dabc 0x374f9000 + 674492
11  Foundation                     0x351a3e6c 0x35151000 + 339564
12  My Game               0x0006325c 0x1000 + 402012
13  My Game               0x00003c98 0x1000 + 11416
14  My Game               0x00062108 0x1000 + 397576
15  My Game               0x00003b08 0x1000 + 11016
16  My Game               0x000074d8 0x1000 + 25816
17  CoreFoundation                 0x375466fc 0x374f9000 + 317180
18  CoreFoundation                 0x375465d6 0x374f9000 + 316886
19  My Game               0x0005c818 0x1000 + 374808
20  My Game               0x000596a4 0x1000 + 362148
21  CoreFoundation                 0x37542a3c 0x374f9000 + 301628
22  My Game               0x000b692c 0x1000 + 743724
23  My Game               0x000b7550 0x1000 + 746832
24  My Game               0x000c2a7c 0x1000 + 793212
25  UIKit                          0x358f4ea8 0x358d3000 + 138920
26  UIKit                          0x358f44dc 0x358d3000 + 136412
27  UIKit                          0x358d7c94 0x358d3000 + 19604
28  UIKit                          0x358d73ac 0x358d3000 + 17324
29  GraphicsServices               0x33e77c80 0x33e72000 + 23680
30  CoreFoundation                 0x3752f5c4 0x374f9000 + 222660
31  CoreFoundation                 0x3752f582 0x374f9000 + 222594
32  CoreFoundation                 0x3752182e 0x374f9000 + 165934
33  CoreFoundation                 0x37521504 0x374f9000 + 165124
34  CoreFoundation                 0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
35  GraphicsServices               0x33e76d1c 0x33e72000 + 19740
36  UIKit                          0x3591d574 0x358d3000 + 304500
37  UIKit                          0x3591a550 0x358d3000 + 292176
38  My Game               0x000030a4 0x1000 + 8356
39  My Game               0x00003010 0x1000 + 8208

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35d8f974 0x35d5a000 + 219508
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35e5e2fc 0x35d5a000 + 1065724
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35e5dd68 0x35d5a000 + 1064296
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35e5d788 0x35d5a000 + 1062792
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35de6970 0x35d5a000 + 575856
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35ddd2fc 0x35d5a000 + 537340

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35d5b3b0 0x35d5a000 + 5040
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35d5d894 0x35d5a000 + 14484
2   CoreFoundation                 0x37521f7c 0x374f9000 + 167804
3   CoreFoundation                 0x37521780 0x374f9000 + 165760
4   CoreFoundation                 0x37521504 0x374f9000 + 165124
5   CoreFoundation                 0x37521412 0x374f9000 + 164882
6   WebCore                        0x3318bd14 0x33070000 + 1162516
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35de5b44 0x35d5a000 + 572228
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x35dd77a4 0x35d5a000 + 513956

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e74f308
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x00238cfc      r6: 0x00238ff0      r7: 0x2fdfdd2c
    r8: 0x3eba21b8    r9: 0x0000000a     r10: 0x3eba21bc     r11: 0x0022fb00
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfdd2c      lr: 0x35de3ac5      pc: 0x35de3ad0
  cpsr: 0x000a0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xebfff +My Gamearmv6  <15bbbead83159dac341a987c660d2b28> /var/mobile/Applications/2968E5FB-96DD-443D-B386-D68F08E9345E/My Game.app/My Game
  0x1f8000 -   0x1f9fff  dns.so armv6  <88b569311cca4a9593b2d670051860d1> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6  <617f6daf4103547c47a8407a2e0b90de> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30229000 - 0x30268fff  MBXGLEngine armv6  <9d60c44b1ddc55387a0cb77f90660b37> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/MBXGLEngine.bundle/MBXGLEngine
0x3027c000 - 0x3027efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f42bbbf67195a7b98d67ad021bba4784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3027f000 - 0x3038dfff  CFNetwork armv6  <d6eeee83216ee9c553134f069f37cbc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x303ef000 - 0x303f4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <f41df4b358b77b29ff85e0eaea88ee1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x303f5000 - 0x30444fff  Security armv6  <cf625b4dc7ea928891313444ef64a7cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30445000 - 0x3055cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <8968ff3f62d7780bb1bd75026a7628d0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3055d000 - 0x30561fff  ApplePushService armv6  <0560b630d26e261e205fc58942e1885c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3059d000 - 0x305a8fff  MobileWiFi armv6  <c7532e63e083a1dd2a0ef7352b85749d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x305aa000 - 0x30612fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <9d264733fc675943c082bd3b9b567b59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30613000 - 0x3064dfff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <beb473ce80390554bb4af21554522286> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3065c000 - 0x3066efff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <51e7bb18da9afa44a33e54e42fbd0707> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3066f000 - 0x306c6fff  CoreMedia armv6  <cd5e9398c161f129146931e888e1c92e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x306f0000 - 0x306fefff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <84592e96bae1a661374b0f9a5d03a3a0> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x306ff000 - 0x30729fff  PrintKit armv6  <74f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3072e000 - 0x307d0fff  AVFoundation armv6  <da9d96f32791f51ecb439c5eaeeff59a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x307d7000 - 0x3082afff  IOKit armv6  <20da5e822f21a8d0a7c5b3e149330efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30831000 - 0x3083bfff  AccountSettings armv6  <eca67ab04f724e1fa7c6406c88e75433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30a04000 - 0x30aa3fff  ProofReader armv6  <2734920b62f174c17aeeb15f371615ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x30ad6000 - 0x30b1afff  AddressBook armv6  <1f30c3370dad27331a491ba4b190813c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30b3d000 - 0x30b9cfff  CoreAudio armv6  <ccc4bace0d6eca79a32ed84d566f72e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32d7d000 - 0x32d89fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <f74f359de7bbe3ccdc37fa6f332aebf4> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32d95000 - 0x32e5cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <429841269f8bcecd4ba3264a8725dad6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x32e5d000 - 0x32ecdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <87b9bb47687902d9120d03d1da9eb9fc> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32f0c000 - 0x32f1ffff  libmis.dylib armv6  <dba9c086b49bd9540930ff27211570d6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33055000 - 0x33061fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <fd0c472436b3306f5b56118c93c8a423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33062000 - 0x3306ffff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <2b68516e1321011a4efbee2947d463c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33070000 - 0x338bffff  WebCore armv6  <aa3b6827f051da7a3494c9bee4ebe290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33ab4000 - 0x33ab4fff  Accelerate armv6  <cdde24a7ad004b2b2e600cd4f3ac5eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33bbc000 - 0x33c0afff  CoreText armv6  <16c9582fdffb598178287c6ce9fd6897> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33c16000 - 0x33d73fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <aec6b54ffd532bb607aab4acbab679b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x33d85000 - 0x33e71fff  QuartzCore armv6  <77cd91ff21fe6c58c309f2c82eb95ca5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33e72000 - 0x33e81fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <af20aba0ec96e7b7c42bb55ac763c784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ead000 - 0x33f6efff  ImageIO armv6  <0c1b6f466667ff345f2399d8142a9d10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33f78000 - 0x33f79fff  CoreSurface armv6  <5e290514380c626e9b0f9f9985b9dc7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34137000 - 0x34156fff  EAP8021X armv6  <fa56845b5396c3ebb368c2368331643c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x343a0000 - 0x343bffff  Bom armv6  <f41bef81e23e2bff59155e5ce46762d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343c0000 - 0x344bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <3547c92c1efc0522b087e7f10eba7728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x344be000 - 0x34500fff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <397723a33c19c3487d304d69580acbfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34b52000 - 0x34f1ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <0eb734c91165416224b98c943ff6476b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34f20000 - 0x35014fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <01916d6784f4de8f3746978faae9c5fa> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35015000 - 0x35022fff  CoreVideo armv6  <7b100fd5fdf98db1cd0f0649e7f6f316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35151000 - 0x35272fff  Foundation armv6  <6bdeb19a1fcb93e2930dadb50416f881> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3529b000 - 0x352a6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <6aa8a4ed0906a495d059ace9125f525d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x352dc000 - 0x35342fff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <11a3677a08175a30df1b3d66d7e0951a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35406000 - 0x35406fff  vecLib armv6  <8f914b3e8a581d49fb21d2c0ff75be03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35407000 - 0x3540afff  MobileInstallation armv6  <456ed7fe6dd9fcd8e78df425085b1452> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x354be000 - 0x354dcfff  OpenAL armv6  <e86dc71ad650db8a13e4785e9c35a4b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x35541000 - 0x35547fff  MBX2D armv6  <fad4955cab36e0179df6f8f27d365b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35815000 - 0x3581afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <224b3cf992a01814f91481244e3213eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3581b000 - 0x35877fff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <7c1049f20c4e64591c09d3ac00c7d3ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x358bc000 - 0x358c3fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <f470dea180ddf23886df75eb256d3888> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x358cc000 - 0x358cffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <bed95ed187350ce27d22ed241ef892ea> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x358d3000 - 0x35d4ffff  UIKit armv6  <14ec6c926b8bda71b73136f6e1a6ac1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35d5a000 - 0x35e98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <70571c1e697e2ae7f7a9b1a499453bb6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35f7e000 - 0x35fc2fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <101dbbcd34cc3231a8be3fd6392556aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fdb000 - 0x36162fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <9a1d72fa9549d83abc1e735ba37a4dc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36179000 - 0x36255fff  WebKit armv6  <83da207070be989ba81dba3a83d5206a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36269000 - 0x36278fff  OpenGLES armv6  <37eda5ddcff210dd321157da35a87a5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x363f3000 - 0x363f9fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <2d83bf6a43bab972d77a1a6e0f3b03d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x365db000 - 0x365f9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <9c94634beea733e754dc115737b6e63c> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36746000 - 0x3683cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <9c44d05cc67f1ebabd795903e581724e> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3683e000 - 0x36888fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <cfc94cfa17958f2f94c9eff208a7dace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3694c000 - 0x3694ffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <74e0f77cc276a9412be268c795fdcbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36955000 - 0x36a1ffff  Celestial armv6  <11172a6ee53bdf067548cd4496bc5fe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36a2d000 - 0x36a30fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <00bc60f690e6328b64e7a7b718edf45a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36a31000 - 0x36a74fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <cabbce0fa7630065dc7e7d3ca3bc616c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36c1c000 - 0x36c26fff  AggregateDictionary armv6  <f7429444c955e4f13c6761d20032ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36c2b000 - 0x36de1fff  AudioToolbox armv6  <bb65e8ed531fe5923eb8ac00a7c0d87d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36de2000 - 0x36e16fff  AppSupport armv6  <783e14db9585fd063c0c2a755cd121b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36e17000 - 0x36e2dfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <006723906b8ac250c1681a1821fbe94d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x37141000 - 0x37184fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <207f362e707871e74a292cfd1ea7893d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x372aa000 - 0x37477fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <21ceabd0e5de17ad4e883c85fcd34d51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37478000 - 0x3747dfff  IOSurface armv6  <ffd66ca04dfe7d382d6961f0df3839ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3748d000 - 0x374f8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <eccd1d7183e73587b2c0aa5755a19c39> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x374f9000 - 0x375e4fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <ab0eac0ddd5b4ae1bf8541116e3c0bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3760a000 - 0x3760bfff  DataMigration armv6  <d2de7c0db77278484236669c2cdccabb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37731000 - 0x37736fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <bd1c480607cc286288db1ca1aec64180> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x377f6000 - 0x37817fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <22c6da37f3adf325f99c3a0494e04c02> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.fram
```

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: refer this link:- http://iphoneobjectivec.blogspot.com/2011/01/tracking-down-excbadaccessexccrash.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the dSYM file that Xcode creates during the build to symbolicate the crash log.
Read [this article](http://furbo.org/2008/08/08/symbolicatifination/) for more information.

Another way is using the "atos" command line command.
For example I have a crash in my app "MyApp" and there is a line in the crash file saying: "2   MyAPP                               0x00041fd4 0x1000 + 266196".
After using the atos command with

```
atos -arch arm -o ~/workspace/svn/MyApp/build/Distribute-Adhoc-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp 0x00041fd4
```

it will return:`-[PushSMSTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (PushSMSTableViewController.m:93)`

You had to replace the path to the dSYM file with your own. The subpath to the DWARF folder in the dSYM file is always available.

Be aware that you use the corresponding dSYM file to you crashed app. If you are using the wrong dSYM file you will get the wrong line number.

Comment: @seenu - @AlexVogel is right. This crash log has only the binary memory addresses for the stack trace. You need to symbolicate this crash log to have your strack trace. (Then you can see where did the application crash).

Comment: If you Build And Archive then the dSYM file will be saved for you automatically and you can simply double-click on a crash report from that build of the app to symbolicate it and make some sense of it.

Comment: @AlexVogel- in that article, it says "you can’t tell where the code is crashing".

Comment: @Moszi - what is the process to see where did the application crash.

Comment: @seenu - actually if you start the application in XCode on the device, then you can debug it ;)

Comment: @seenu - Yes in an unsymbilcated crash log it is hard to say what the cause of crash is. But after symbolicating the file lines like "My Game               0x0006325c 0x1000 + 402012" will be displayed as for example "My Game               0x0006325c [MyGameClass methodWhereAppCrashes]" and you can see where the application did crash

Comment: @seenu - i had the same issue - the solution that worked for me is, all crash logs are saved in the itunes application data folder, copy/drag drop the crash log into xcode's orgnizer -> device logs window. That will show more readable information like which thread it crashed at and what was the exception that raised.

Comment: @veeru i did this already but for me not showing the thread crashed for which exception

Answer (score 0):

@alexVogel is right. 
another simple way to generate & safely place dSYM file is using building action: `Build and Archive`(you can find it under menu/build section)